# Run web server locally without exposing it publicly?

Tags: python, nginx

I am running a dedicated server on Digital Ocean. My site uses Flask on NGINX through Gunicorn. During development I plopped a search engine (solr) on a local VM (through VMWare Fusion) which happens to be running Tomcat. It could have been running any web server per my question. In my app I make all search requests to that local ip: `192.168.1.5`. Now, when I install Tomcat on my server and run it you can see it publicly at `mysite.com:8080`. There's the old welcome screen of Tomcat for the world to see.  I want my app to be able to access it locally through `localhost:8080` but not show it to the world. Is this possible?

Comment: The OP is using Digital Ocean, a hosting provider... so I don't think that would work

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes RE: duplicate. I believe you are correct. That does seem to answer my question. I just did not know how to phrase it. 
It's a dedicated server so I have complete control over it.

Comment: Yeah you need to know the correct term is 'binding' to an IP address, otherwise it can be hard to find.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no.
While using a hosting plan, so actually anything that you are doing is 'exposed to the world' since you yourself have to access it remotely, like everyone else.

You have two options, the first, configure the Digital Ocean server to only accept connections from your public IP, and the second, keep using your development server locally until you are ready for primetime.

Comment: When I say exposing it to the world I am talking about a ip address or domain that links to a webpage or a service that anyone can access. I do not think you understand the question. I could install or upload plenty of things on that server that are not accessible to everyone.